# How I modify date and time of mdf and ldf files when database created or modified?

Tags: sql-server

I want to backup modified `.mdf` and `.ldf` files in SQL Server, but after adding new table or add data into table, `.mdf` and `.ldf` files are not getting modified.

So in latest backup newly changes are not reflected. What should I do for modify `.mdf` and `.ldf` files when SQL Server writes?

Comment: You should ***NOT*** under any circumstances fiddle around with the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files yourself! Let SQL Server handle those - and for backup - use the **built-in T-SQL `BACKUP`** command - that's much easier and that's **the way to do it**

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is not modified?

After adding a new table or data, the `mdf` and `ldf` files' modified date or size don't change unless it needs to grow.

To my understanding, the modified date/time changes only when

1. database open(like server restart, db recreated, restored etc.)
2. data file grows/shrinks
3. `dbcc checkdb`

If you like to backup `mdf` files, you need turn the database offline to back it up, afterwards turn it back online. The modified date will reflect it.
I suggest you use sql `backup` command to backup database and leave it online.

```
backup database yourdb to disk='path\filename' with init; (check BOL for details)
```